# Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'KurseviApp.Kurs' to 'KurseviApp.Student'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to make simple app with many to many relationship (courses/students). In my language is (kurs/student).

This is my course class

```
namespace KurseviApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class Kurs
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Kurs()
        {
            this.Student = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public int PK_Kurs_ID { get; set; }
        public string Naziv_Kursa { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Izabrani { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my students class

```
namespace KurseviApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Student
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Student()
        {
            this.Kurs = new HashSet<Kurs>();
        }

        public int PK_Student_ID { get; set; }
        public string Broj_Indeksa { get; set; }
        public string Ime { get; set; }
        public string Prezime { get; set; }
        public string Godina { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Kurs> Kurs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I have done it pretty well so far. But the problem appears when I am creating new course and selecting students for. This is my code in controller

```
private kurseviEntities db = new kurseviEntities();

public ActionResult Add(int id = 0)
{
    Kurs ks = new Kurs();
    using (db)
    {
        ks.Student = db.Student.ToList();
    }
    return View(ks);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Kurs kurs)
{
    using (db)
    {
        db.Student.Add(kurs); //THIS LINE IS A PROBLEM
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

It gives me error which I wrote in article title. If I delete the line, course is created successfully but I'm still missing adding students to course. Every help is welcome, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is my view

```
@model KurseviApp.Kurs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}
<h2>Add</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PK_Kurs_ID)
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Naziv_Kursa, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Naziv_Kursa, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Naziv_Kursa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        <label>Odabir studenata</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Izabrani, 
    new SelectList(Model.Student, "PK_Student_ID", "Ime"), 
    new { @class="choosen-select", id = "normalDropDown" })
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="submit" />
    </div>
}

@section scripts {
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $("#normalDropDown").chosen({ width: "15%" });
    });    
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Kurs` and `Students` are separate types of things; `db.Students` is a list of `Students` and you're trying to add a new `Kurs` into that list directly.  My guess is that you want to get a specific student and then call `student.Kurs.Add(kurs)` to add the `Kurs` to the kurs list of the specific student.

Comment: Yes you guessed corectly. I edited post and added my view. So how I should do that? To get a specific student?